# Fastest way to search multiple fields mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I currently have a name and surname fields in a mysql user table, and a search box where they can enter both, so my query is basically

```
SELECT name,surname FROM user
WHERE CONCAT(name,' ',surname) LIKE '@search%'
```

This works fine, but gets pretty slow on a large tables even though both the name and surname columns are indexed and when the search is broken up it's pretty quick, is there a way to index the concatenated fields or are they already indexed when both the fields are indexed and would it be faster to switch to full text indexing?

Comment: Using concat will prevent MySQL from using an index as it is a derived value. It's long winded by using OR is your best bet. `WHERE name LIKE '@search%' OR surname LIKE '@search%'`.

Comment: If you don't mind gaining speed at the expense of more space and maintenance logistics, you can add an indexed column of the concatenated columns and search that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct is assuming that `@search` is replaced by something?

If you are searching for "words", then `FULLTEXT` works *significantly* faster.  But, be aware of its limitations (stop words, min word length, etc).

That particular attempt, `CONCAT(name,' ',surname) LIKE '@search%'`, would only check the beginning of `name` for '@search'; I doubt if that is what you wanted.  What did you want?

Keep in mind that `name LIKE '@search%'` is a lot faster than `name LIKE '%search%'` because it can use `INDEX(name)`, which I assume you have?

If you have both `INDEX(name)` and `INDEX(surname)`, then *this* would be reasonably fast:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE name LIKE '@search%'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT ...
    WHERE surname LIKE '@search%';
```

This is because both indexes can be used.  Otherwise, they are *unlikely* to both be used; instead there would be a "table scan".  (The use of `OR` will not do as well if you have an old version of MySQL.)

However, if the user starts `@search` with '%' or '_', it will be sloooow because the leading wildcard will cause a table scan.

Meanwhile, if you don't check for various special characters, you are *very subject to SQL Injection*!

**After clarification**

Since the user is typing the names separately, you can much more easily test:

```
WHERE name    LIKE '@name%'
  AND surname LIKE '@surname%'
```

Then have both of these (in case the user shortens either one):

```
INDEX(name, surname)
INDEX(surname, name)
```

Those are *better* than what you have, `INDEX(name), INDEX(surname)`.

Since the data input seems to be a single field, use your client programming language for splitting it into @name and @surname.  (It is possible, but messy, in SQL; see `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.)

Read about "composite indexes" to understand why these indexes are better, and why the original `CONCAT` is especially inefficient.

Comment: Yes @search is replaced by the search, what I need is if the name and surname are typed seperated by a space as the search text, (i.e. 'Rick James' ) the user with the name Rick and surname James should be returned. I could do WHERE name LIKE '@search%' and surname LIKE '%@search%' but this would break the index on the surname and give me the same issues, I could use full text for the surname but the limitations could be an issue if only one or two character s of the surname are entered, i.e. 'Rick Ja'

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This assumes the start of your search includes the first name until completed to continue followed by the last name.

As long as your search doesn't have a wildcard at left you can always index both your name and surname fields as one index as shown in the MySQL manual reference for multi column indexes here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Then let's force the query to use the multi-col index.  The steps are:

1.) Create the index

```
CREATE INDEX fullname ON table_name (name, surname)
```

2.) Use *index hinting* to tell MySQL to use your multi-column index in the query

```
SELECT name,surname FROM user USE INDEX (fullname) WHERE CONCAT(name,' ',surname) LIKE '@search%'
```

When the LIKE comparison is made it will use the index going left to right so long as no wildcard '%' is at the beginning of your search.

The best option really is to change your fields to FULLTEXT and take advantage of the new FULLTEXT search features of MYSQL.  Here's a good example from MySQL's site showing how easy this kind of search is to implement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html